# Uncaught type error: cannot read property only locally

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an error in my javascript only when I run it locally, but when I run it on jsfiddle it works fine.

**Javascript**

```
var pos, scrollY, 
    $el               = $('nav'),
    navItems          = $el.find('> span'),
    menuHeight        = $el[0].clientHeight,
    sections          = $('section').toArray(),  // cache elements
    pointOfAttachment = $el[0].getBoundingClientRect().top;

// Bind events
$(window).on('scroll.nav', updateNav)
         .on('resize.nav', updateNav);

function updateNav(){
    scrollY = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;

    for( var i = sections.length; i--; ){
        if( sections[i].getBoundingClientRect().top - menuHeight < 0 ){
            navItems.filter('.' + sections[i].id).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
            break;
        }
        navItems.removeClass('active');
    }

    if( scrollY > pointOfAttachment )
        $el.addClass('fixed');
    else
        $el.removeClass('fixed');
}

// for initial page load
updateNav();

$("nav span").click(function() {
    var sectionId = $(this).attr('class')
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: ($('#'+sectionId).offset().top - $('nav').height()) + 1
    }, 300);
});
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
<script src="script.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<header>Header</header>
<nav>
  <span class='a1'>Section 1</span>
  <span class='a2'>Section 2</span>
  <span class='a3'>Section 3</span>
</nav>
<div id='navPlaceholder'></div>

<section id='a1'>Some section..</section>
<section id='a2'>Another Section</section>
<section id='a3'>And another one</section>
</body>
</html>
```

When I run it on JSfiddle it works fine but when I run it locally I get the javascript error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'clientHeight' of undefined

Can anyone tell me why this would only happen locally, and how I can fix it please?

Comment: Perhaps you don't have `<span>`s that are immediately children of `<nav>` ?

Comment: can you check this line var sectionId = $(this).attr('class') and add ; in the end

Comment: So `$el[0]` is undefined. Maybe just wait for the DOM to be ready

Comment: @A.Wolff that what i was thinking. In JSfiddle it typically run js after onLoad event of the page.

Comment: I added the HTML to the code above. I don't know how to change the load preferences locally I'm afraid

Comment: You are calling `script.js` before any element is added to the BODY. If you include this script just before the `</body>` closing tag, it will work as expected

Comment: wrap all your js code with: `$( document ).ready(function() { YOURCODE});`

Comment: A wolf that works, please can you add it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should include `script` once DOM is ready:

```
   <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript">
</body>
```

For example here, just before `</body>` closing tag